# Superior variety?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

*The **superior variety** of rice is quite expensive

Is **superior variety** grammatically correct? Or should it be **variety superior**?

Comment: Superior is an adjective, and adjectives generally precede nouns in English, so *superior variety* is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Superior variety is grammatically correct and here is an analysis:

**Definition of *Superior***

(adjective)

1.Higher in rank, status, or quality.

---

**Definition of *Variety***

(noun)

1.The quality or state of being different or diverse;

---

As a general rule in English language, you can use an adjective before a noun.

***Example***

**The way of the *superior man*** (Grammatically Correct!)

---

**You should not use a noun before an adjective.**

***Example***

The way of the *man superior* (Grammatically Incorrect!)

---

Therefore, ***the superior variety of rice is quite expensive*** is a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: *Variety* in relation to crops like rice usually means a specific taxonomic category. See definition 2 [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/variety)